Is it correct to say "Be careful, you're gonna run over your brother's foot with your scooter"?
This is the context, my daughter is riding her scooter in the living room in my house while her little brother is walking around there.
In the Oxford dictionary, it says

run somebody/something <-> over
​(of a vehicle or its driver) to knock a person or an animal down and
drive over their body or a part of it
Two children were run over and killed.
My dog almost got run over.

What I understood is that, I can say "the vehicle ran over my foot" or "the vehicle's driver ran over my foot".
Say you are the vehicle's driver so "the vehicle's driver ran over my foot" will become "you ran over my foot". But I think "you ran over my foot" is ambiguous.
Without a context, is "You're going to run over your brother's foot" ambiguous? Maybe, you are literally running over his foot with your feet in the air actually over his foot.
So I guess we can make it clearer by saying  "you ran over my foot with your scooter".
Is it correct to say "Be careful, you're gonna run over your brother's foot with your scooter" in this situation?

What are you considering ambiguous? "You ran over my foot" obviously refers to whatever vehicle you are or were operating.

If I say "Write your name." (or "Viết tên bạn.") --  is that ambiguous?

No it's not ambiguous.
This is an example of an expression that at first glance seems ambiguous to ELL students, but in reality the meaning is clear to any native speaker.
Suppose I am running along the beach, and I approach a woman lying sunbathing on a beach towel. Suppose I continue running, leaping over the woman in the course of that run. If I understand correctly, you are asking whether we would describe that as running over the woman. I wouldn't. You can see that, in order to make my meaning clear, I introduced leaped over (or jumped/stepped over) to explain my actions.
In fact, the idea of physical contact is so closely associated with run over that if you told me the above story and said you ran over the woman, I would think that you stepped on her, not over her.

It is fine with or without the preposition phrase as the sentence will be understood from context:
You're going to run over your brother's foot (with your scooter).
We should say going to rather than gonna.

without a context, is "You're going to run over your brother's foot" ambiguous?--> You are literally running over his foot with your feet in the air actually over his foot.

We rarely say things without context.  Without context, we would need to specify more, as what you’ve suggested in your post.
The phrase run over someone’s foot or feet is normally used to describe the action of water or vehicles but not the scenario you described.

"You are literally running over his foot with your feet in the air actually over his foot." The likelihood of someone understanding the sentence in that way is extremely remote.

English doesn't use the construction "run over {an object | a creature}" not in connection with a vehicle of some kind.  If you're jogging and tread on a phone that someone dropped, we wouldn't say "You ran over a phone". We'd probably say something like "You stepped on a phone."

When I was out jogging this morning I stepped on a phone that someone must have dropped. I was cutting across the playing field and didn't see it lying in the grass.
When I was out biking this morning I ran over a phone that someone must have dropped. It blended in with the color of the sidewalk.

